# JavaScript if statement returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, mootools

Does anybody knows why this snippet returns `false` even if the passed string is "Active"?

```
if ($('status_'+id).getText()=="Active")
```

I've also tried changing the code to

```
if ($('status_'+id).getText()==String("Active"))
```

and

```
if (String($('status_'+id).getText())=="Active")
```

and still no luck.

I've also checked `$('status_'+id).getText()` through `console.log` to verify if it really returns "Active"

i wonder why it doesnt work?
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question: are you sure the returned string doesn't contain spaces?

Answer (score 1):

The first step in any debugging task is to check your assumptions. Use a debugger or a series of alerts to check the following:

- what's the value of id?
- does$('status_'+id) evaluate to a DOM
  element?
- what does
  $('status_'+id).getText() actually
  return